# Uppercase or lowercase for all Turkish characters at DB2

Tags: sql, db2, uppercase, lowercase, turkish

I try to get upper or lower of all Turkish characters.

at DB2 there is a function TRANSLATE but it don't want to use it as

```
TRANSLATE(:SITE 'I','i')
TRANSLATE(:SITE 'O','ö')
TRANSLATE(:SITE 'U','ü')
```

I don't want to keep Turkish characters, I'd like to convert all Turkish characters at the same function.

For example, I try to convert                                                              'i' to 'I' ,                                                                               'ö' to 'O' and                                                                           'ü' to 'U'

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

There's LCASE and [UCASE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0052927.html) functions:

```
db2 => values(ucase('a b c ç d e f g ğ h ı i j k l m n o ö p r s ş t u ü v y z', 
       'tr_TR'))

1
---------------------------------------------------------------
A B C Ç D E F G Ğ H I İ J K L M N O Ö P R S Ş T U Ü V Y Z

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Hi leons, your solution makes 'i' to 'İ' but i need 'i' to 'I', 'ö' to 'O' and 'ü' to 'U'

Comment: Ah. You should be able to use TRANSLATE to that but I've run into some character width issues with that. Someone suggested an Xquery-based stored procedure alternative here: http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1695900-sql0176n.html#post6600632